# For each loop with items from an array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach, items

Can anyone help me convert my current loop to a loop that does not contain an index or length. I need it to print the ages and names within the array. The loop I have worked as is but the instructions say to avoid using an index and length.

```
var personArray = [{ name: "Michael", age: 30 }, { name: "Gabriel", age: 21}, { name: "Caesar", age: 50 }];
  for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++){
    writeToPage(personArray[i].name + " = "+ personArray[i].age);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const writeToPage = console.log;

var personArray = [{ name: "Michael", age: 30 }, { name: "Gabriel", age: 21}, { name: "Caesar", age: 50 }];

personArray.forEach(o => writeToPage(o.name + ' = ' + o.age));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me, it ended up breaking my code

Comment: @codingcat don't include the `const writeToPage = console.log;` part; that was just to allow me to keep the same function name in the `forEach`